# Why 'They hanged' rather than 'You hanged' in Al Hanissim?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, purim, haman, al-hanissim

In Al Hanissim on Purim, we praise Hashem [directly](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Amidah%2C_Thanksgiving.5?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְאַתָּה בְּרַחֲמֶיךָ הָרַבִּים. הֵפַרְתָּ אֶת עֲצָתו. וְקִלְקַלְתָּ
>   אֶת מַחֲשַׁבְתּו. וַהֲשֵׁבותָ לּו גְּמוּלו בְּראשׁו. וְתָלוּ אותו
>   וְאֶת בָּנָיו עַל הָעֵץ -  In great mercy **You** frustrated his
>   counsel and ruined his plan, and **You** returned his plan upon his
>   own head and **they** hanged him and his sons upon the tree.

However, when thanking Him for hanging Haman and his sons, we revert to "they" rather than "You" - why?

Comment: maybe because non-Jews did the hanging?

Comment: frustrating the plan and changing the fate was divine, but the hanging was done by others

Answer (score 4):

It's quoting the pasuk.

> וּבְבֹאָהּ֮ לִפְנֵ֣י הַמֶּלֶךְ֒ אָמַ֣ר עִם־הַסֵּ֔פֶר יָשׁ֞וּב מַחֲשַׁבְתּ֧וֹ הָרָעָ֛ה אֲשֶׁר־חָשַׁ֥ב עַל־הַיְּהוּדִ֖ים עַל־רֹאשׁ֑וֹ **וְתָל֥וּ אֹת֛וֹ וְאֶת־בָּנָ֖יו עַל־הָעֵֽץ׃**
>
> https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.9.25

Comment: As with earlier lines in Al Hanissim too. (I've always wondered if Al Hanissim for Chanukkah preserves original Hebrew from the book of Maccabees)

Answer (score -1):

it was a great challenge for ester to actually not have mercy on him and children 
due to the sin of shaul hamelech her zaide 
and she had to fix that

also see targum how on way to hang him he raised 
with mordechai a raukuss
that he should kill him by sword  
to no avail

yet chazal  say they both almost failed

so really it’s part of the ness that they succeeded in hanging him